# Magento 2: How to add customer address programmatically?

Tags: magento2, programmatically, customer-address

I have successfully created a customer programmatically. Now I want to add an address to this customer. How can I do this programmatically?

Comment: how did you created a customer programatically please

Answer (score 25):

Using `Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface;`  you can create customer address.

```
namespace {NameSpace};

/**
 * Description of Address
 */
class Address {

/**
 * @var Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory
 */
protected $addressDataFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $addressRepository;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory
) {
    $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
    $this->addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
}

public function saveCustomer()
{
    $address = $this->addressDataFactory->create();
    $address->setFirstname($firstName)
            ->setLastname($lastName)
            ->setCountryId($countryId)
            ->setRegionId($regionId)
            ->setRegion($regionName)
            ->setCity($city)
            ->setPostcode($postcode)
            ->setCustomerId($customerId)
            ->setStreet($street)
            ->setTelephone($telephone);

    $this->addressRepository->save($address);
}
```

Comment: Great! let's take this next level...according to my requirement...how can i check that if given address is already exist or not?if yes,then i've to create address else i've to skip.

Comment: +1 for the answer. I also want to add the `Landmark` in my address. I tried by adding `->setLandmark($landmark)` but it doesn't work for me. How could I set it along with this?

Comment: @Amit Bera How to save custom attributes? ->setMycustom() not working

Comment: Good answer, saved my time +1:)

Comment: It's really helpful code but can you say me how can assign default address multiple customer id's programmatically

Comment: Is there any way I can get the entity_id of saved customer shipping address. Which saves in table customer_address_entity.

Answer (score 5):

Please try with following code.

```
$customerId = 10

$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');

$address = $addresss->create();

$address->setCustomerId($customerId)

->setFirstname('test')

->setLastname('last')

->setCountryId('IN')

->setPostcode(10000)

->setCity('Bangalore')

->setTelephone('1234567890')

->setCompany('BNG')

->setStreet('XYZ street')

->setIsDefaultBilling('1')

->setIsDefaultShipping('1')

->setSaveInAddressBook('1')

$address->save();
```

Comment: Upvoted... (y) its also working

Comment: This one worked fine for me .

Answer (score 1):

Try it, It works for me.

```
private function save_customer($JsonParam) {
        echo "<PRE>";
        print_r($JsonParam);
        exit;
        $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
        $url = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storeManager = $url->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend');

        // Customer Factory to Create Customer
        $customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
        $websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
        $store = $storeManager->getStore();  // Get Store ID
        $storeId = $store->getStoreId();

        // Instantiate object (this is the most important part)
        $customer = $customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($JsonParam->Email);
        if (!$customer->getId()) {
            $customer->setEmail($JsonParam->Email);
            $customer->setFirstname($JsonParam->FirstName);
            $customer->setLastname($JsonParam->LastName);
            $customer->setPassword('Admin@123');
            $customer->save();

            $addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
            $address = $addresss->create();
            $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                    ->setFirstname($JsonParam->FirstName)
                    ->setLastname($JsonParam->LastName)
                    ->setCountryId($JsonParam->Country)
                    ->setPostcode($JsonParam->Zip)
                    ->setCity($JsonParam->City)
                    ->setState($JsonParam->State)
                    ->setTelephone($JsonParam->Phone)
                    ->setCompany('Arhamsoft Pvt. Ltd.')
                    ->setStreet($JsonParam->Address1 . " / " . $JsonParam->Address2)
                    ->setIsDefaultBilling(false)
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
                    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
            $address->save();

            $addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');
            $address = $addresss->create();
            $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
                    ->setFirstname($JsonParam->FirstName)
                    ->setLastname($JsonParam->LastName)
                    ->setCountryId($JsonParam->BillingCountry)
                    ->setPostcode($JsonParam->BillingZip)
                    ->setCity($JsonParam->BillingCity)
                    ->setState($JsonParam->BillingState)
                    ->setTelephone($JsonParam->Phone)
                    ->setCompany('Arhamsoft Pvt. Ltd.')
                    ->setStreet($JsonParam->BillingAddress1 . " / " . $JsonParam->BillingAddress2)
                    ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
                    ->setIsDefaultShipping(false)
                    ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
            $address->save();

            echo 'Create customer successfully' . $customer->getId(); exit; 
        } else {
            //email already exists 
            echo 'Email already exists'; exit; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this update the NULL value of customer_entity table column "default_shipping", "default_billing"?

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

***I Did check and its working proper***

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');

        $address = $addresss->create();

        $address->setCustomerId($customerId)

            ->setFirstname($FirstName)

            ->setLastname($LastName)

            ->setCountryId($countryid)

            ->setPostcode($postcode)

            ->setCity($city)

            ->setTelephone($telephone)

            ->setFax($fax)

            ->setCompany($Company)

            ->setStreet($Street)

            ->setRegion($region)

            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        $address->save();
```

***And if you want to set default billing & shipping address just add 2 line like below***

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$addresss = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory');

        $address = $addresss->create();

        $address->setCustomerId($customerId)

            ->setFirstname($FirstName)

            ->setLastname($LastName)

            ->setCountryId($countryid)

            ->setPostcode($postcode)

            ->setCity($city)

            ->setTelephone($telephone)

            ->setFax($fax)

            ->setCompany($Company)

            ->setStreet($Street)

            ->setRegion($region)

            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')

            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')

            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');

        $address->save();
```

Comment: Dont use $objectManager