# Magento 2 : Custom attribute of address not saving

Tags: magento2, custom, customer-address

I am using following code and trying to save `SetLatitude()` or  `->setCustomAttribute('latitude',$address['latitude'])`   but it's not working.
I followed this [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/241879)

```
      <?php
namespace ABC\Customerapi\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException; 
class Customerapi implements \ABC\Customerapi\Api\CustomerapiInterface
{
    CONST MAX_PASSWORD_LENGTH=12;
    CONST MIN_PASSWORD_LENGTH=4;
    private $customerFactory;
    private $storeManager;
    private $_request;
    private $_tokenModelFactory;
    protected $addressDataFactory;
    protected $addressRepository;
   # protected $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Rest\Request $request,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
         \Magento\Integration\Model\Oauth\TokenFactory $tokenModelFactory,
       # \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterfaceFactory $addressDataFactory
        ){
            $this->_request             = $request;
            $this->storeManager         = $storeManager;
            $this->_tokenModelFactory   = $tokenModelFactory;
            $this->customerFactory      = $customerFactory;
         #   $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
            $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;
            $this->addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
    }

    public function update($shop_name,$mobile,$email=null,$address,$customerId){
        try{

            $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
            $customer->getResource()->load($customer, $customerId);
            $name_Array = $this->split_name($shop_name);
            if($email){
               $customer->setEmail($email);  
            }

            $customer->setFirstname($name_Array[0]);
            $customer->setMobile($mobile);
            $customer->setLastname($name_Array[1]);            
            $customer->getResource()->save($customer);
            if($address){
                $data = ['block'=>$address['block']];
                $addressModel = $this->addressDataFactory->create();
                $addressModel->setFirstname($address['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($address['lastname'])
                    ->setCountryId($address['country_id'])
                    ->setRegionId($address['region_id'])
                    #->setRegion($address[''])
                    ->setCity($address['city'])
                    ->setPostcode($address['postcode'])
                    ->setCustomerId($customerId)
                    ->setStreet(array($address['street']))
                    ->setTelephone($address['telephone'])
                    ->setBlock($address['block']);
                    #->setData($data);
                    #->setCustomAttribute('preferred_calling',$address['preferred_calling'])                
                    #->setCustomAttribute('latitude',$address['latitude'])                
                    #->setCustomAttribute('longitude',$address['longitude']);
                    $this->addressRepository->save($addressModel);
            }
            $message = [
                'status'=>200,
                'id'=>$customerId,
                'message'=>'account has been update successfully'
            ];
            echo json_encode($message);
            exit;
        }catch(\Exeption $e){
             throw new InputException(
                __($e->getMessage())
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Setup script:

```
$customerSetup -> addAttribute('customer_address',
            'latitude',
            [
            'label' => 'Latitude',
            'system' => 0,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'position' => 100,
            'sort_order' =>100,
            'visible' =>  false,
            'required'      =>  false,
            'default_value' => '',
            'note' => '',


                        'type' => 'varchar',
                        'input' => 'text',

            ]
            );

        $customerSetup -> getEavConfig() -> getAttribute('customer_address', 'latitude')->setData('is_user_defined',1)->setData('default_value','')-> setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_register_address', 'customer_address_edit'])-> save();
```

Comment: Can you please add your full code? I mean construct.

Comment: @RohanHapani please check now

Comment: @Kanika check you customer address attribute, its is_system value is 0 and allowed to edit in form or not.

Comment: @Technocracker I have added setup script please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this out to your setup script.

```
public function install(
    ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
    ModuleContextInterface $context
) {
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    $customerAddressEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer_address');
    $attributeSetId = $customerAddressEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'latitude', [
        'label' => 'Latitude',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'required' => false,
        'position' => 333,
        'visible' => true,
        'system' => false,
        'is_used_in_grid' => false,
        'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
        'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
        'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
        'backend' => '',
        'comment' => 'latitude'
    ]);


    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer_address', 'latitude')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address','customer_address'
            ]
        ]);
    $attribute->save();
}
```

hope this will work for you!.

Comment: that was fixed,  your answer is correct there was issue in setup script

Comment: thanks @Kanika.. happy to help you.

Comment: This answer worked on my case as well!! Well done!! Thank you